# How to set expiration for @Cacheable in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, cache-expiration

I have the following cache implementation in a Spring Boot app and it is working without any problem. However, I want to define expiration for this approach. Is it possible to set expiration for `@Cacheable`?

I look at **[Expiry time `@Cacheable` spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968157/expiry-time-cacheable-spring-boot)** and there is not seem to be a direct way for `@Cacheable`. Is it possible via a smart approach?

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class SimpleCacheCustomizer 
  implements CacheManagerCustomizer<ConcurrentMapCacheManager> {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager) {
        cacheManager.setCacheNames(asList("users"));
    }
}
```

```
@Cacheable("users")
public List<User> getUsers(UUID id) {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-specific-config), there is no TTL for the default cache system of Spring.

> 8.7. How can I Set the TTL/TTI/Eviction policy/XXX feature?

> Directly through your cache provider. The cache abstraction is an
> abstraction, not a cache implementation. The solution you use might
> support various data policies and different topologies that other
> solutions do not support (for example, the JDK
> ConcurrentHashMap — exposing that in the cache abstraction would be
> useless because there would no backing support). Such functionality
> should be controlled directly through the backing cache (when
> configuring it) or through its native API

You'll have to use an other cache provider like `Redis` or `Gemfire` if you want a `TTL` configuration.

An example of how to use `TTL` with `Redis` is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60561141/10691359).

Comment: Thanks a lot,I also realized it. But how can I use Redis or Gemfire in my implementation above? I tried to use another one as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202700/spring-cacheable-default-ttl, but now worked

Comment: Could you post as an example code by integrating it to the approach above?

Comment: I've answered your question. If you have a problem with a `Redis` configuration, you should create an other post and show us what you did and what did not work. In the meantime, I can give this URL https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-redis-cache which show you how to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In this scene I need to use other cache providers instead of `@Cacheable` I think. So, which one should I prefer for my Spring Boot? Redis, EhCache, JCache, etc. ?

Comment: For large scale distributed app, you should prefer `Redis`, otherwise, you can pick `EhCache` for a simple quick in-memory cache. Both are good.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if it solve your first issue.

Comment: I tried that approach on Baeldung, but it gives the following error: 

"org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException:

Comment: I can't help you much without the code, but it seems you need to make an object serializable.

Comment: I use another example on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-redis-cache. I hope it is also a good example for Redis. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a `LocalDateTime` object. For example:

```
@Cacheable(value="forecast", key = "#date.toString()")
public void forecast(LocalDate date){
    //
}
public void call(){
    forecast(LocalDate.now());
}
```

Cache will expire after 1 day.

Positive aspect - it does not require a scheduled job.

Negative aspect - old data remains cached.